# Identify Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I read a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261390/linear-subspace-vector-subspace) and have a better understanding of what subspace is

> Let $V$ be the set of vectors $\langle x,y,z\rangle\in\Bbb R^3$ such that $x-y+2z=0$ and $x+y+4z=0$; then $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

In order to show this, you must show three things:

(1) $V$ is non-empty.
(2) $V$ is closed under vector addition: if $\vec u,\vec v\in V$ then $\vec u+\vec v\in V$.
(3) $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication: if $\vec v\in V$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then $\alpha\vec v\in V$.

**I don't understand what "V is closed" mean in this definition**

There's an example from the textbook *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang:

> Find the subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ that are actually subspaces.
>
> (a) The plane of vectors $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ with $b_1 = b_2$
>
> (b) The plane of vectors with $b_1 = 1$
>
> (c) The vectors with $b_1b_2b_3 = 0$
>
> (d) All linear combinations of $v = (1, 4, 0)$ and $w = (2, 2, 2)$
>
> (e) All vectors that satisfy $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0$
>
> (f) All vectors with $b_1 \leqslant b_2 \leqslant b_3$

The correct answer is (a), (d) and (e).

For (a), we know $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ belongs to $\Bbb R^3$, so definition (1) is satisfied. But for definition (2) and (3), since $b_1, b_2, b_3$ $\in  \Bbb R$, isn't it $b_1 + b_2 + b_3$  $\in  \Bbb R$ as well?

For (b), it only says The plane of vectors but it doesn't say how many b's are there. so we cannot garentee is its $\Bbb R^3$. Is this the correct reasoning?

For (c), same reason for (a), $b_1 * b_2 * b_3 \in  \Bbb R$, which is not $\Bbb R^3$. So (c) is false

For (d), since multiplication and addition will make $\Bbb R^3$, so (d) is correct.

For (e), even though it says "All vectors that satisfy $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0",$ the multiplication is already $\Bbb R$... Why is it true?

For (f), same question as (e)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I don't understand what "V is closed" mean in this definition**

The meaning of "closed" is precisely stated afterwards in symbols:

> (2) $V$ is closed under vector addition: if $\vec u,\vec v\in V$ then $\vec u+\vec v\in V$.
>   (3) $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication: if $\vec v\in V$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then $\alpha\vec v\in V$.

In words, slightly informal: (all) **sums** of elements of the set have to stay in the set and (all) **scalar multiples** of elements in the set have to stay in the set.

To show that a subset *isn't* a subspace, it suffices to find a counter-example to the conditions above.

> (b) The plane of vectors with $b_1 = 1$

Then, for example, the element $(\color{blue}{1},1,1)$ is in the subset (because $b_1=\color{blue}{1}$) but the scalar multiple $2\cdot (1,1,1) = (\color{red}{2},2,2)$ isn't (because $b_1=\color{red}{2} \ne 1$), so **not all** scalar multiples stay in the subset, hence it is not a linear subspace.

Or, with the sum condition: $(\color{blue}{1},0,1)$ and $(\color{blue}{1},1,0)$ are in the subset, but their sum $(1,0,1)+(1,1,0) = (\color{red}{2},1,1)$ isn't.

---

If you understand this, try finding simple counter-examples for (c), (d) and (f) as well.

When a subset is in fact a subspace, you cannot prove this by using one or more examples. In that case you'll need to show that the conditions (non-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication) hold *in general*.

Your textbook probably gives an example of how to do this: check if the zero vector is in the subset (non-empty) and then pick some arbitrary element(s) to verify the other two conditions.

---

**Additions after comment**

> For (c), I think it is incorrect because even though $b_1b_2b_3=0$, it is possible that $(b_1, b_2, b_3) = (-1, 1, 0)$. So $3 \cdot (−1,1,0)=(−3,3,0)$, and $b_1$ and $b_2$ do not stay in the subset.

No, that's not right since also $(−3,3,0)$ is in this. You have to check whether $b_1b_2b_3=0$ and $-3 \cdot 3 \cdot 0 = 0$. Notice that the requirement $b_1b_2b_3=0$ means that *at least one* coordinate is $0$.

**Hint**: find two elements with this property, but such that their sum doesn't have the property.

> For (d), I don't quite understand what "all linear combination" means.

All the linear combinations of $v=(1,4,0)$ and $w=(2,2,2)$ are all the elements of the form $a \cdot (1,4,0)+b \cdot (2,2,2)$ for any real numbers $a$ and $b$.

> For (e), I thought it is similar to (c), but why is (e) correct?

The counter-example to (c), see the hint above, does not work for (e).

Either show it in general (take two arbitrary elements et cetera) or, alternatively: note that if $b_1+b_2+b_3=0$, then any element $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ is of the following form:
$$(b_1, b_2, \color{blue}{b_3})=(b_1, b_2, \color{blue}{-b_1-b_2})=b_1 \cdot (1,0,-1) + b_2 \cdot (0,1,-1)$$so you're looking at all the linear combinations of $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ and the result is similar to part (d). Or in yet another way: geometrically $b_1+b_2+b_3=0$ represents a plane through the origin in the coordinates $b_1$, $b_2$, and $b_3$ and planes through the origin are subspaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! For (c), I think it is incorrect because even though $b1b2b3 = 0$, it is possible that (b1, b2, b3) = (-1, 1, 0). So $3 * (-1, 1, 0) = (-3, 3, 0)$, and b1 and b2 do not stay in the subset. For (d), I don't quite understand "all linear combination" means. Does it mean $(b1, b2, b3) * v + (b4, b5, b6) * w$ ? For (e), I thought it is similar to (c), but why is (e) correct?

Comment: @munmunbb I addressed the questions in your comment in a new part of my answer; see above.

Comment: finally got it!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

All "is closed under an operation" means is that performing the operation on members of that set produces new members of that set. ([See here for the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)).)

In this specific case, $V$ is closed under addition if and only if, for any vectors $v_1, v_2$ in V, if we perform the operation of addition with them, the resulting vector $v_1 + v_2$ is again in $V$.

Likewise, $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication if and only if, for any vector $v$ in $V$, if we multiply it by an arbitrary scalar $\lambda$, then the resulting vector $\lambda v$ is again in $V$.

For (a) and (c), you seem to be confusing a vector $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$ with its components, $b_1, b_2, b_3$. It is a subtle difference, but an important one. If we add two vectors in the plane, we add their components element-wise, e.g. if we have $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3), c = (c_1, c_2, c_3)$, then $b+c = (b_1 + c_1, b_2 + c_2, b_3 + c_3)$.

For (b), the reasoning is unfortunately not correct. The set is non-empty, since the vector $b = (1, 0, 0)$ is in it.

The reasoning for (d) is unfortunately also incorrect. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a three-dimensional vector space, which can be spanned by only at least three vectors. But the space in question is spanned by only two vectors.

(e)-(f) I don't understand what you mean by the "multiplication is already $\mathbb{R}$.